# Wrapping R's plot function (or ggplot2) to prevent plotting of large data sets

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bigdata

Rather than ask how to plot big data sets, I want to wrap `plot` so that code that produces a lot of plots doesn't get hammered when it is plotting a large object.  How can I wrap `plot` with a very simple manner so that all of its functionality is preserved, but first tests to determine whether or not the object being passed is too large?

This code works for very vanilla calls to `plot`, but it's missing the same generality as `plot` (see below).

```
myPlot <- function(x, ...){
    isBad <- any( (length(x) > 10^6) || (object.size(x) > 8*10^6) || (nrow(x) > 10^6) )
    if(is.na(isBad)){isBad = FALSE}
    if(isBad){
        stop("No plots for you!")
    }
    return(plot(x, ...))
}

x = rnorm(1000)
x = rnorm(10^6 + 1)

myPlot(x)
```

An example where this fails:

```
x = rnorm(1000)
y = rnorm(1000)
plot(y ~ x)
myPlot(y ~ x)
```

Is there some easy way to wrap `plot` to enable this checking of the data to be plotted, while still passing through all of the arguments?  If not, then how about `ggplot2`?  I'm an equal opportunity non-plotter.  (In the cases where the dataset is large, I will use hexbin, sub-sampling, density plots, etc., but that's not the focus here.)

---

Note 1: When testing ideas, I recommend testing for size > 100 (or set a variable, e.g. `myThreshold <- 1000`), rather than versus a size of > 1M - otherwise there will be a lot of pain in hitting the slow plotting.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you have is that as currently coded, `myplot()` assumes `x` is a data object, but then you try to pass it a formula. R's `plot()` achieves this via methods - when `x` is a formula, the `plot.formula()` method gets dispatched to instead of the basic `plot.default()` method.

You need to do the same:

```
myplot <- function(x, ...)
    UseMethod("myplot")

myplot.default <- function(x, ....) {
    isBad <- any((length(x) > 10^6) || (object.size(x) > 8*10^6) || 
                    (nrow(x) > 10^6))
    if(is.na(isBad)){isBad = FALSE}
    if(isBad){
        stop("No plots for you!")
    }
    invisible(plot(x, ...))
}

myplot.formula <- function(x, ...) {
    ## code here to process the formula into a data object for plotting
    ....
    myplot.default(processed_x, ...)
}
```

You can steal code from `plot.formula()` to use in the code needed to process `x` into an object. Alternatively, you can roll your own following the [standard non-standard evaluation rules (PDF)](http://developer.r-project.org/nonstandard-eval.pdf).

Comment: +1 For the insight on what's going on and for the very useful pointer to the standard nonstandard reference.  Can you clarify where I can find the code for `plot.formula`?  I suppose that any code that extracts objects from a formula will work, so I'm also looking for that.

Comment: @Iterator `graphics:::plot.formula` or `getAnywhere(plot.formula)` will show the code. `methods(plot)` will show what S3 methods are available for the plot generic. Note that `plot.formula` is shown with a `*` in the output from `methods()`, indicating that the function itself is not exported from the namespace; instead it is registered as an S3 method for dispatch.

Comment: @Iterator For extracting objects from formula's the standard non-standard rules are the prevailing paradigm in R - plot.formula appears to use this idiom though it is made more complex by the need in that function to also grab info on the object names extracted from the formula with which to label the plot axes. See the PDF I linked to for simpler details on the main steps needed to extract the objects. You'll also need more arguments in the formula method than I showed. Again see the PDF for the arguments needed to exploit this idiom fully.